# New user profile page!  

Tags: discussion, user-profile-page, stackexchange

A redesigned user profile page is online on meta.stackoverflow.com, the meta site for the entire stackexchange network. They're looking for feedback before they release the new layout for the entire network.

Since now is certainly the best time to give feedback before it's too late I wanted to share this with tex.sx. (I'm not sure how I like these changes.) Here's what it'll look like:

[image: new user profile page]

Click the picture to go to the [discussion on meta.so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112151/162565).

Comment: This switched over to the main site *today*.

Comment: Yup. I really like it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now implemented. ([It was implemented 2011-11-28](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59446/163868).)